# Getting modulus and publicExponent from java PublicKey

Tags: java, android, rsa, public-key-encryption

Hi all I get the public key as follows

> OpenSSLRSAPublicKey{modulus=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,publicExponent=10001}

by using the bellow code

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg;
KeyPair kp;
PublicKey publicKey;
kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
publicKey = kp.getPublic();
```

now i want to get the **modulus** and **publicExponent**  from this.

Can any one suggest please...?

Comment: There's no question here.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast the [`PublicKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/PublicKey.html) to an [`RSAPublicKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAPublicKey.html), e.g.:

```
RSAPublicKey rsaPub = (RSAPublicKey) kp.getPublic();
BigInteger modulus = rsaPub.getModulus();
BigInteger publicExponent = rsaPub.getPublicExponent()
```